# How do I store an array of objects that are a result of an ajax query pulling data from JSON in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I was able to successfully retrieve my JSON objects using the code below. When I log the variable "value2", I can see the values in my console. However I am unable to populate my "arraytest" with value2. When I print the value of arraytest in the console after the function runs, the array is empty.

```
    var accessURL = "https://lots-of-holes.firebaseio.com/.json";
    var arraytest= [];
    i=0;
    $.getJSON(accessURL, function(data){
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $.each(value, function (index2, value2) {               
                arraytest[i++] = value2;
                console.log(value2);
        });
      });
    });
    console.log(arraytest);
```

It may be something to do with the query running slower than my javascript but I am not sure how to handle this. If you think it is something else and would like to still help, please message me and I will give you a link to my sourcecode. I am new to javascript and ajax.

The JSON is below:

```
{"-37 932570096604465 * 101 68831543328787":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":-37.932570096604465,"lon":101.68831543328787},"-79 14830348215878 * -147 67984075199726":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":-79.14830348215878,"lon":-147.67984075199726},"-9 566696357885519 * -86 19132124619011":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":-9.566696357885519,"lon":-86.19132124619011},"23 175286370699936 * -14 694988385655307":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":23.175286370699936,"lon":-14.694988385655307},"25 686572941892038 * -54 7326350327119":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":25.686572941892038,"lon":-54.7326350327119},"39 2538061 * -76 7143967":{"frequency":10.0,"lat":39.2538061,"lon":-76.7143967},"39 2538512 * -76 7144418":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":39.2538512,"lon":-76.7144418},"39 2543882 * -76 7132241":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":39.2543882,"lon":-76.7132241},"39 2543986 * -76 7133143":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":39.2543986,"lon":-76.7133143},"52 0353479004271 * 147 31906570837452":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":52.0353479004271,"lon":147.31906570837452},"7 568992516106547 * 37 95350231539729":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":7.568992516106547,"lon":37.95350231539729},"78 51991220059591 * 69 61956909362064":{"frequency":2.0,"lat":78.51991220059591,"lon":69.61956909362064}}
```

Comment: `arraytest.push(value2)`

Comment: I had that before but same issue

Comment: I updated it, thanks!

Comment: The Json is not relevant. The problem of the OP is $.getJSON async function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.getJSON` is an async function. So the `console.log(arraytest)` is running before that the arraytest is populate.

You can try this:

```
    var accessURL = "https://lots-of-holes.firebaseio.com/.json";
    var arraytest= [];
    i=0;
    $.getJSON(accessURL, function(data){
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $.each(value, function (index2, value2) {               
                arraytest[i++] = value2;
                console.log(value2);
        });
      });
    console.log(arraytest);
    });
```

Comment: Ah okay I can see the array being populated now, but I would like to use this array later on in my code. After I come out of the function the array still remains empty

Comment: You should use a callback function in your $.getJSON(accessURL, callback) if you need use this array immediately. In other case, of course your array is populated (a few seconds depends of the user's connection)

Comment: Can you please update the solution? I am not exactly sure how I would do that

Comment: What's your problem? You can use the arraytest in other function (a few seconds after). In case that you need run a specific function you should pass in the second parameter of the $.getJSON instead the anonymous function.

Comment: oh okay that makes sense! Thank you so much